# Why is preg_match behaving differently to preg_replace (resulting in different matches) in php?

Tags: php, regex

Given the following string and regular expression, the resulting behavior is something I don't understand. preg_match delivers what I am expecting while preg_replace doesn't make sense to me.

```
$string = 'aaa [Ticket#RS-123456] äüö [xxx] ccc ddd';
$re = '@(.*)?(\[Ticket\#)(.*)(\])(.*)?@siU';
```

What I finally need in this example is the string **RS-123456** (or whatever string would be at this position). This string should match at the 3rd position ($3), if I don't completely misunderstand regular expressions.

```
preg_match($re, $string, $matches_pm);

Result (as expected):
Array(
    [0] => aaa [Ticket#RS-123456]
    [1] => aaa 
    [2] => [Ticket#
    [3] => RS-123456 // That's exactly what I would expect
    [4] => ]
)


$res_pr = preg_replace($re, "$3", $string);

Result (unexpected):
RS-123456 äüö [xxx] ccc ddd
```

I hope anyone can open my eyes and show me where my logical failure is hiding.

Comment: Apparently [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) handles the [`U` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) while [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) ignores it. You should use `[^\]]*` instead of `.*` after `Ticket#`. Btw, `#` is not a meta-character, it doesn't need to be escaped. And `]` also doesn't need to be escaped when it appears outside of a character class. Your `regex` should be `@(.*?)(\[Ticket#)([^\]]*)(])(.*?)@si`.

Comment: Usually preg_replace handles the U modifier; I am using it quite often. And in this case preg_replace delivers different results with and without the ungreedy modifier. Thanks for the escaping hints. I tend to escape way too much, just to rule out possible errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both match the same text, but `preg_match` returns the first match only while `preg_replace` replaces the match (*that is not the entire string*) with Group 3 contents leaving `äüö [xxx] ccc ddd` in the resulting string.

Use

```
$re = '@(.*)(\[Ticket\#)(.*?)(\])(.*)@si';
```

to get the same results with `preg_match` and `preg_replace`.

See the [PHP demo](http://rextester.com/WTO56104).

However, `preg_match` is the preferred way here:

```
if (preg_match('@\[Ticket#\K[^]]+@i', $string, $matches_pm)) {
    echo $matches_pm[0];
}
```

See [this PHP demo](http://rextester.com/YNNG11111).

**Pattern details**

- `\[Ticket#` - a literal `[Ticket#` substring
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the currently matched text
- `[^]]+` - 1 or more chars other than `]`